# Ajax jQuery Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i have been searching for about 2-4 hours on stackoverflow but couldn't find my solution.

My code should alert the data value. But it only gives out: Illegal invocation

Code: (Javascript)

```
    function getData () {

$(document).ready(function() {

   var withdraw = $('#withdraw').val();
   var deposit = $('#deposit').val();
 });
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/house_info.php",
        data: {  
               'withdraw' : withdraw,
               'deposit' : deposit
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert(data.test);
        },

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText );
        }
    }); 

return false;
}
```

Code: (HTML)

```
            <form action='#' method='something'>
        Withdraw: <input type='text' id='withdraw' />
        Deposit: <input type='text' id='deposit' />
        <input type='submit' onClick='getData()' />
        </form>
```

Code: (PHP (ajax proceed file)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['deposit']))
{
    $output["test"] = "Test";
    echo json_encode = $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

var withdraw has local scope. So it will become null while using in ajax. just use $('#withdraw').val(); in ajax call.
Remove the action='#' and method='something' from the form

```
  function getData(){
    var withdraw = $('#withdraw').val();
    var deposit = $('#deposit').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../ajax/house_info.php",    // type full url
     data: 'withdraw='+withdraw+'&deposit='+deposit,
     success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.test);
       }
    }); 
  }
```